# How to read/print specific column and rows python csv

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I'm trying to read through a csv file (rows and columns like a spreadsheet) and and have it find specific point of data given 2 arguments

> def main(a, b):

where a is the column and b is the row so that if I type in "A, 2" it would give me the name of the column (A) and the number in row 2. I'm not sure how to approach this.

This is what I tried

```
def data(a, b):

    file = open("file.csv")
    csv_file = csv.reader(file)

    for line in csv_file:
        array = line.split(",")
        first_item = array[0]

    a = len(array)
    csvfile.seek(0)

    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=" ")

    for row in reader:
        b = list(row[a] for a in included_cols)
    print(content)
```

Comment: you need to show what you have tried, are you able to open and parse the csv file?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file into a 2D array and then use a, b to index into the array

```
def data(a, b):
   array = []
   with open("file.csv") as file:
      for line in file.readlines():  
           array.append(line.split(","))
      print array[a][b]
```

Using with open("file.csv") as file, will close the file when you exit the with block of code

Comment: print(array[a][b])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str 

I keep getting this error, I think its b/c when I enter the values for a and b, the first one is a string for the columns (a, b, c, etc) while the second value is a int